# Как использовать кастомные эмоции в embed message .addfield

Tags: c#

вообщем мне нужно в embed message в .addfield добавить кастомную эмоцию как это сделать? я только умею дефолтные эмоции дискорда использовать к примеру :fire: - \U0001f525. 
библиотека discord.net

Comment: Также, как и стандартные? Они все имеют свое "ключевое слово".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Нет если не верите мне, сами попробуйте

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  он просто в эмбед сообщении выводит :name emoji:

Comment: Вы правильно ввели имя? Пробел там обычно заменяется нижним подчеркиванием. Также не все поля поддерживают форматирование и эмодзи. Я вам давал конструктор, там пробовали вставить хотяб стандартный эмодзи? Например - `:thumbsup:`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ winner :dartlang: вот что выводит к сожаления скрин здесь не могу приложить

Comment: Ага, серверные эмоции по другому немного работают. Напишите в чат дискорда "\" и выберите эмоцию, в чате будет нечто подобное `<:pepeScoots:579776505941327872>`, вот это попробуйте и отправлять. Также у Discord.net есть класс [Emote](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.Emote.html), который имеет методы для работы с Emoji. Также вы можете нужную вам эмоцию взять через `guild.Emotes.First(e => e.Name = "my-custom-emote");`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Кстати я пофиксил проблему с кастомными эмоциями, вы дали правильный ответ на 50% нужно чтобы ещё эмоция которую ты записуешь в коде была на сервере

Comment: А может быть иначе? Ну а так я вас лишь пытаюсь направить в правильное направление, не более. По этому не пишу ответов, своего бота писать ради одного ответа не очень хочу)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну да вы правильно говорите, ну в данном случае не ваша вина, ибо в доке не написано, что кастомная эмоция должна быть на сервере загружена, ну а до такого не сразу додумаешься.